# Autocomplete issue: Content is not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

Content is not displaying is autocomplate list as you can see in screenshot below.

[image: Autocomplete Error]

I am getting this response.

> [{"emp_number":1,"fname":"Arslan","lname":"Hassan"},{"emp_number":2,"fname":"Muneeb","lname":"Janjua"
>   },{"emp_number":3,"fname":"hr","lname":"user"},{"emp_number":4,"fname":"test","lname":""} .......... **REMOVED TO MAKE IT LOOK BETTER HERE** .......]

My JS Code:

```
$( "#search-emp" ).autocomplete(
{
    source: function (request, response)
    {
        var form_data = {
            ajax                : '1',
            name                : $("#search-emp").val(),
            actioncall          : 'search-emp'
        };

        $.ajax({
            //contentType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "_ajax.php",
            data: form_data,
            success: function( data )
            {
                response( data );
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:3,
    select:function(evt, ui)
    {
        alert(ui.item.emp_number);
    }
});
```

I want to display `fname` and `lname` on selected into `input` field.

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` before `response(data)` and add to question to see what the server respond. There list should have name or some specific key for the fields that will be displayed.

Comment: @DanielDudasI have aded response to my question. Please have a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem it's because jQuery autocomplete wants to have 2 fields named `label` and `value`. The content from `label` will be displayed in the autocomplete.

Because your server return other name for the keys you have 2 options:

1. Change the server to return a json like:

   `[{"emp_number":1,"fname":"Arslan","lname":"Hassan", "label":"Arslan Hassan", "value": "Arslan Hassan"},....]`
2. Or on the success callback from ajax create an array with this fields (`label` and `value`) and pass this array to `response()` callback.

You can find more informations here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Thank you. I changed the `json` response as you suggest. It worked not but only one issue. I am getting only First name filled in `input` field.

Comment: @Hassaan You need to concat first name with last name to `label` so both will be displayed in autocomplete.